# Error when creating iOS Framework project with CoreData - "An NSManagedObject of class 'Item' must have a valid NSEntityDescription."

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, frameworks

Platform: Mac Mini M1 2020 8Gb, XCode 13.1, iOS 15.0, iPhone11 Simulator

The problem: I cannot get CoreData to work in a Framework project. Here's a minimal project which demonstrates the issue (the code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/XenonApps/AppleCoreData)) :

1. I created a simple SwiftUI App with 'UseCore Data' & 'Include Tests' options selected and named it 'AppleCoreData'.
2. Added the following Test class and successfully built and tested the creation of the PersistenceController.preview with the pre-populated Item data:

```
class AppleCoreDataTests: XCTestCase {
    var dataController: PersistenceController!

    override func setUp() {
        dataController = PersistenceController.preview
    }
    
    func testCanCreatePersistenceController() {
        
        XCTAssertNotNil(dataController)
    }
}
```

3. I created a new Framework project with 'Include Tests' option checked and dragged copies of the 'AppleCoreData' data model and 'Persistence' class into the project. Project built without errors.
4. I created the following 'Store' class to encapsulate persistent storage functionality without exposing the underlying implementation.

```
public class Store {
    
    let name: String = "AppleCoreData"
    public let isPreview: Bool
    var controller: PersistenceController
    
    init(isPreview: Bool = true) {
        self.isPreview = isPreview
        self.controller = isPreview ? PersistenceController.preview : PersistenceController.shared
    }
}
```

5. Added the following test:

```
class AppleCoreDataModelTests: XCTestCase {
    
    var store: Store!

    override func setUp() {
        store = Store()
    }

    func testStoreCreation() {
        XCTAssertNotNil(store)
    }
}
```

6. Test produced this error: >Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value) which I fixed by changing the boilerplate code in the PersistenceController from this:

```
if inMemory {
    container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
}
```

to this:

```
if inMemory {
    if let firstDescription = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first {
        firstDescription.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
    } else {
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions.append(NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")))
    }
}
```

7. The project builds successfully but now when I run the test I get this error: "An NSManagedObject of class 'AppleCoreDataModel.Item' must have a valid NSEntityDescription."

I have tried a number of fixes suggested to people with similar problems but none of them have fixed the issue.

I have spent many hours scratching my head on this problem and am now completely bald! :-D

Can anyone help please?

[Here is a link to code on GitHub](https://github.com/XenonApps/AppleCoreData)

**UPDATE**
Following @Joakim_Danielson's suggestion, I amended the PersistenceController's init() method as follows:

```
    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"AppleCoreData", withExtension: "momd")!
        let model = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "AppleCoreData", managedObjectModel: model)
        if inMemory {
            if let firstDescription = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first {
                firstDescription.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
            } else {
                container.persistentStoreDescriptions.append(NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")))
            }
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
    }
```

Now I get a fatal error on the first line of the init() method because it cannot locate the resource 'AppleCoreData.momd'. Here is a screen shot of the Build folder contents:
[Build Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAknH.png)

I'm new to SwiftUI development and am finding it hard to find relevant, up-to-date documentation on issues such as these.

Comment: It's really hard to follow this question but if I create a new iOS project with Core Data  included using Xcode 13.2 it builds and runs just fine straight out of the box.

Comment: Thanks Joakim, the main issue is about using CoreData in a Framework template project. I have no problem using CoreData in the SwiftUI App template.

Comment: Ok, I missed that. How is your Core Data model loaded, I didn't see any code for that in your project?

Comment: The AppleCoreDataModelTests class instantiates a Store object which encapsulates the PersistenceController in either .preview or .shared version. I haven't got as far as loading any data yet because the test fails on instantiating the Store in either case.

Comment: Yes and it most likely fails because it can't find the model. See for instance [this article](https://ishabazz.dev/blog/2020/7/5/using-core-data-with-swift-package-manager)

Comment: Still stuck!! See update for latest attempt. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can't use `Bundle.main` when in a framework since that refers to the apps bundle. For a swift package you can use `Bundle.module` so try that instead

Comment: So, are you saying that the _only_ way to a have reusable data model using CoreData is to create a Swift Package? This doesn't make sense to me. What I really want is either a static or dynamic library or Framework that can be shared amongst multiple projects. I find it hard to believe this is not possible!

Comment: No I am in no way saying that, I am only referring to swift packages because that is what I have experience of when it comes to using Core Data outside the main app and I thought that my knowledge still might be helpful even if it doesn't concern frameworks directly.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood. Using `Bundle.module` gives a compiler error "Type 'Bundle` has no member 'module'". The `Bundle` class has an initializer `init(for:)` which according to the documentation can be used to "locate the framework bundle based on a class defined in that framework." This sounds promising so I'll give it a try. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @apps2go have you had any luck with this? I'm investigating this issue as I faced it in my own project lately. .bundle comes from an extension created in a Swift package target and doesn't come from UIKit itself, so it's not easily available for other project types (like Framework). Any luck with init(for:)? Have you solved your problem eventually, and if yes, how?